# What's the proper way to refer to all the code in `core/lib/Drupal`, or the code in `core/lib/Drupal/Core' or `core/lib/Drupal/Core/Foo`?

Tags: 8

When we say 'core' we mean the whole of Drupal core that you get from the Drupal project page.

On D7, core code that wasn't in modules tended to be called 'the includes' IIRC.

But on D8 they're not include files any more. They in `core/lib/Drupal` and we have:

- `core/lib/Drupal`
- `core/lib/Drupal/Core`
- `core/lib/Drupal/Components`
- `core/lib/Drupal/Core/Foo`
- `core/lib/Drupal/Components/Foo`

What's the correct way to refer to these?

Comment: Oh gee, I wonder what that `lib` stands for.

Comment: _they're not include files any more_ Yeah they are, they're just included via a PSR autoloader rather than directly now. I doubt this question will have an answer that isn't just an individual's personal preference

Comment: @Clive You could also say that the majority of Drupal 7 files weren't includes, either, in the PHP sense of manually using `require()` and friends.  Most files were managed by the Module API, and that exposed a way to handle things that couldn't be wired up magially.

Comment: What I meant was that on D7 they were files called `includes/foo.inc` and now they're not.

Comment: "I doubt this question will have an answer that isn't just an individual's personal preference" -- right, but then why don't we have a standard way of referring to these so we're not confused?

Comment: @NoSssweat I'm not sure what you're trying to get at, but your comment doesn't seem helpful to me.

Answer (score 4):

What you describe is correct, when you install Drupal, everything in the 'core' directory is considered the core set of Drupal files, or the bare minimum installation package.

The files in 'core/lib' is essentially all of the source code for the running system.  Personally, this is what "core" means to me.  The files (for the most part<sup>1</sup>) outside of that are the scaffold (or support files).

The files in 'core/lib/Drupal/Core' are called "Core", pronounced with a big C.  The files in 'core/lib/Drupal/Component' are called "Component", pronounced with a big C.  Confusing, yes?

"Component" are the set of files that Drupal uses, but don't actually rely on anything else in "Core".  For example, `DateTimePlus` and `Time` are two Components, that don't need anything in 'core/lib/Drupal/Core'.

"Core" are the set of files that Drupal uses, but are interdependent on each other, and also require "Component".  For example, `DrupalDateTime` relies on `DateTimePlus` (in Component) and the Language subsystem (in Core).

<sup>1</sup>Ignoring tests for this discussion.

Comment: "pronounced with a big C. The files in 'core/lib/Drupal/Component' are called "Component", pronounced with a big C. Confusing, yes" -- Yes. Where's the plan to fix this?